# How to hide stereotypes labels from my profile

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have created a new profile for activity diagram in EA(Enterprise Architect).
The stereotype I created is named `dummy`. The profile is created with some activity diagram elements, but I use elements from my newly created profile, on top of each element, something like is seen with element name `«dummy»` followed by the element name.

I would like to know if there is a way to hide the stereotype label. I have learned about shape script but couldn't figure it out well.

I am using EA version 13.

Answer (score 1):

The only way (I know) is to turn off stereotype display for the whole diagram:

[image]

I first thought that `DrawNativeShape` in the shape script would work, but it also draws the stereotype. And it's near to impossible to show all compartments manually except for the stereotype. Just showing the class name (and individual drawings/texts) is simple. But showing attributes/operations and respecting the feature/diagram settings is near to impossible.

Comment: Since OP is using a stereotype on Activity diagram elements, it probably isn't necessary to display attribute or operations. A simple shapescript could suffice.

Comment: @GeertBellekens That might be true. dasari: can you please give more details about where you want to hide the stereotype?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can hide the << >> with a ShapeScript.

```
shape main
{
    h_align = "center";
    editablefield = "stereotype";
    rectangle(0,0,100,100);
    println("#stereotype#");
    printWrapped("#name#");
}
```

Produces a 100 x 100 box with a stereotype top centre and a name on the next line below.

Some help is provided by Sparx e.g. https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/16.1/modeling_tools/usingtheshapescript.html
but it's pretty limited. It does involve a lot of trial and error.